# The multiprocessing module and global variables

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand multiprocessing and global variables. I tried to declare `pool` in 3 different places:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# 1) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
#pool = mp.Pool( processes = 2 )

def f(x) :
  print x

# 2) no error
pool = mp.Pool( processes = 2 )

a = range(5) 

# 3) no error
#pool = mp.Pool( processes = 2 )
pool.map( f, a)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

My understanding is that the line `pool = ...` spawns children processes, which contain their own copy of the global variables declared until that line in the parent code. They don't have access to global variables declared after that line. Therefore the AttributeError in 1) is expected. The children processes don't know anything about `f`, because it is declared further down in the parent code.

However, I am sure I understand why 2) works. `pool.map` uses both `f` and `a`. Why is it ok for children processes not to know `a`, while they need to know `f`?